# Problems with ionic-react Multiselect

Tags: reactjs, select, ionic4

Im  developing an mobile app with ionic-react, the problem is when i use the multiselect property, it stop to show the selected data.

(Ionic 4 + React ) I'm trying to set data in a hook in a react functional component (React.FC), everything it's ok when i just selecte one item from the select, but stop to show the selected value in the label when i selete more than one

hook declaration:

```
const [riskForm, setRiskForm] = useState({
    id: 0,
    description: '',
    category: 0,
    inherentImpact: 0,
    inherentChance: 0,
    possibleEffects: [],
  });
  const { id, description, category, inherentImpact, inherentChance, possibleEffects } = riskForm;
```

Select implementation:

```
<IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">Posibles Efectos</IonLabel>
              <IonSelect
                multiple
                placeholder="Seleccione..."
                name={'possibleEffects'}
                value={possibleEffects}
                onIonChange={e => updateFormRisk(e)}
              >
                {riskPossibleEffects().map((health: any, i: number) => (
                  <IonSelectOption key={i} value={`[${JSON.stringify(health)}]`}>
                    {health.title}
                  </IonSelectOption>
                ))}
              </IonSelect>
            </IonItem>
```

OnIonChange function updateFormRisk:

```
const updateFormRisk = (event: any) => {
    setRiskForm({
      ...riskForm,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
```

the current result it's that i'm not able to see the data after select more than one item from multiselect